# Ключевое слово this

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, новичку, что значит `this` в этом блоке кода?

Интересует именно эта строка

> `t=new Thread(this);`

```
class Callme{
    synchronized void call(String msg){
        System.out.print("["+msg);
        try{ 
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}

class Caller implements Runnable{
    Callme target;
    String msg;
    Thread t;
    public Caller(Callme target,String msg){
        this.target=target;
        this.msg=msg;
        t=new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
    public void run(){
        target.call(msg);
    }
}

class SynchTest{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        Callme target=new Callme();
        Caller ob1=new Caller(target,"Welcome");
        Caller ob2=new Caller(target,"to the Syncronized");
        Caller ob3=new Caller(target,"World");
        ob1.t.join();
        ob2.t.join();
        ob3.t.join();
    }
}
```

Это пример из Шилдта по использованию потоков...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` - это ссылка на самого себя - то есть на экземпляр класса, в котором разворачивается действо.

Вызывается конструктор `Thread(Runnable )`, роль `Runnable` выполняет класс `Caller`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А можно ли заменить ссылку this? Что бы я полностью понял.

Comment: @Nemezis16


    Runnable self = this;
    t=new Thread(self);


тоже самое

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае this - это указатель на экземпляр класса. 
А сам предлог this вообще-то переводится, как это, этот, или же сей.
Вот и получается, что строку:

```
t=new Thread(this);
```

можно прочитать, как: приравнять к t новый поток из **этого** же объекта; то есть функция Thread сделает поток-наследник от класса Caller.

Ну, как-то так. Могу слегка ошибиться.

Comment: Это указатель не на класс, а экземпляр класса - аккуратнее в терминах...

Comment: Ну да. Сейчас поправлю.